# Can't get code to output annual salary total

Tags: java

I have made two classes that extended from the basic "Employee" class. I have shown the Employee, and Salesman class below. I need to configure the Salesman class to show the total annual salary. The employee class prints it no problem, but, I can't get the Salesman class to print annual salary. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the output I'm currently getting:

2014 Employees:

Employee Name: Smuck,Jenna, Monthly Salary=$3,000.00,Annual Salary=$36,000.00

Salesman Name: Joans,Barbara, Monthly Salary=$3,200.00,Annual Sales=$100,000.00

Salesman Name: McMains,Ashley, Monthly Salary=$2,900.00,Annual Sales=$400,000.00

Executive Name: Seibert,Greg, Monthly Salary=$5,000.00,Stock Price=$49.00

Average Salary for all Employees for Year 2014 = $25,891.00

2015 Employees:

Employee Name: Kallinen,Brion, Monthly Salary=$3,100.00,Annual Salary=$37,200.00

Salesman Name: Mentzer,Dickey, Monthly Salary=$4,100.00,Annual Sales=$75,000.00

Salesman Name: Thomas,Carol, Monthly Salary=$3,800.00,Annual Sales=$90,000.00

Executive Name: Tofte,Abby, Monthly Salary=$4,800.00,Stock Price=$190.00

Executive Name: Kuehn,Jennifer, Monthly Salary=$6,000.00,Stock Price=$79.00

Executive Name: Brown,Eric, Monthly Salary=$6,500.00,Stock Price=$51.00

Average Salary for all Employees for Year 2015 = $57,432.67

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I need to get it to also print out the annual salary for the Salesman and Executives.

```
    package AverageSalary;

    public class Employee {

    private String employeeName;
    private double monthlySalary;

    // Constructor that initiailizes name and monthly salary
    public Employee(String EmployeeName, double mnthSalary) {
        employeeName = EmployeeName;
        monthlySalary = mnthSalary;
    }

     //set Employee Name function
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    //get Employee Name Function
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

     //monthlySalary
    public void setMonthlySalary(double monthlySalary) {
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

    public double getMonthlySalary() {
        return monthlySalary;
    }

    // Method named annualSalary returns the salary for a whole year.
    public double annualSalary() {
        return getMonthlySalary() * 12;
    }

    // toString method returns string containing name and monthly salary
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("\nEmployee Name: %s, Monthly Salary=$%,.2f,"
        + "Annual Salary=$%,.2f", getEmployeeName(), getMonthlySalary(), 
        annualSalary());
        }
    }

    ________________________________________________________________________


    package AverageSalary;

    import java.util.HashSet;

    public class Salesman extends Employee{
    private double annualSales;

    public double getAnnualSales() {
        return annualSales;
    }

    // Constructor that initializes name, monthly salary and annual sales
    Salesman(String Name, double mnthSalary, double dblAnnualSales)
    { 
      super(Name, mnthSalary);
      this.annualSales=dblAnnualSales;
    }

    //An overridden method annualSalary that returns the salary for year 
    //Salary of salesman consists of base salary computed from the monthly  
    salary plus a commission. 
    //The commission is computed as 2% of that salesman's annual sales. 
    //The maximum commission a salesman can earn is $20,000.

    @Override
    public  double  annualSalary()
    {
        double dblSalesCommission=0;
        dblSalesCommission=(getMonthlySalary()*12)*0.02;

        if ( dblSalesCommission > 20000)
                dblSalesCommission=20000;

        return getMonthlySalary()+dblSalesCommission;
    }
     @Override
     public String toString()
     {
        return String.format("\nSalesman Name: %s, Monthly         
     Salary=$%,.2f,Annual
     Sales=$%,.2f",
         getEmployeeName(), getMonthlySalary(),
                       getAnnualSales() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear about the problem?
Do you get an exception? If so could you please post the error trace?
In which enviroment are you using these classes (web app, stand-alone, etc)? Bye!

Comment: I'm running it in Netbeans. It compiles and runs good, but it doesn't display the annual salary for the salesman. The only part of the code I'm confused with is the last couple lines. I can't quite figure out how to get it to output the annual salary of the salesman.

Comment: Please format your code that it is easy readable.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also include the output you are currently getting, and what you expect it to be.

Comment: Hi Tamas, sorry for the mistake.. Joe..! I'm, stil not undesranting! Maybe you should just call annualSalary() instead of getAnnualSales() in the toString()... ?

Comment: Are you expecting salary to be different for Employee and salesman? your code is able to output three values in .toString().
E
Salesman Name: S, Monthly Salary=$888,888.00,Annual Sales=$7,777,777.00
E Name++S
MS++888888.0
AS++7777777.0
S
Salesman Name: S, Monthly Salary=$888,888.00,Annual Sales=$7,777,777.00

Comment: I just updated it with the output I'm currently getting. The employee's salary is simply monthly salary * 12. The Salesman's is monthly * 12 + commission. That's where it seems to be messing up. It simply doesn't display the annual salary for the Salesman at all.

Comment: Boo Radley ended up pointing out my mistakes spot on. Thank you for your assistance everyone! Learned a lot today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems that I could find.

Your Salesman `toString()` did not actually print out the annual salary. I changed this to:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String
            .format("\nSalesman Name: %s, Monthly Salary=$%,.2f,Annual Sales=$%,.2f,Annual Salary=$%,.2f",
                    getEmployeeName(), getMonthlySalary(), getAnnualSales(), annualSalary());
}
```

Also, your `annualSalary()` computation was incorrect, you need to multiply the monthly salary by 12 and then add the commission.

```
@Override
public double annualSalary() {
    double dblSalesCommission = 0;
    dblSalesCommission = getAnnualSales() * 0.02;

    if (dblSalesCommission > 20000)
        dblSalesCommission = 20000;

    return (12.0 * getMonthlySalary()) + dblSalesCommission;
}
```

Making these changes produced a correct output for me:

```
Employee Name: Test Guy, Monthly Salary=$5,000.00,Annual Salary=$60,000.00
Salesman Name: Sales Guy, Monthly Salary=$5,000.00,Annual Sales=$100,000.00,Annual Salary=$61,200.00
```

Comment: It's important to note that when you `@Override`a function it **replaces** the functionality.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was trying to do. A couple simple mistakes I just couldn't seem to figure out. I appreciate it so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: One final comment about it though; I did have to change
dblSalesCommission = (getMonthlySalary() * 12) * 0.02;
to 
dblSalesCommission = (getAnnualSales()) * (0.02); 
to get it to compute correctly. Otherwise it was taking 2% of the annual salary, instead of 2% of sales. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calculating annualSalary incorrectly.

It's not clear whether annualSales is the money the Salesman makes from sales in a year, or the number of sales they make in a year. I assume it's number of sales made.

```
// Salary of salesman consists of base salary computed 
// from the monthly salary plus a commission. 
// The commission is computed as 2% of that salesman's annual sales. 
// The maximum commission a salesman can earn is $20,000.



@Override
public double annualSalary() {
    double moneyFromSalary = getMonthlySalary * 12;

    double moneyMadePerSale = // Unknown
    double dblSalesCommission = moneyMadePerSale * annualSales * 0.02;

    if (dblSalesCommission > 20000)
            dblSalesCommission = 20000;

    return moneyFromSalary + dblSalesCommission;
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. I Boo Radley ended up pointing out exactly what I was looking for, but this would definitely work for me as well. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your String.format arguments are garbled. Instead of

```
String.format("\nSalesman Name: %s, Monthly Salary=$%,.2f,Annual Sales=$%,.2f"
```

Try

```
String.format("\nSalesman Name: %s, Monthly Salary=$%.2f, Annual Sales=$%.2f",
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It looks like that was my mistake, plus I didn't do the computation correctly just prior. I got it working now. Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Hooray! It would help me a lot if you would accept my answer please!